# Using jquery to sum column value in a table after filtering

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this in my page:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <caption>
        <h3>Itens do Estrutural</h3>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-md-9">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Filtrar:</span>
            <input type="text" name="filterbox" id="filterbox" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your search here ..." />
        </div><br />
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="info">
            <td colspan="2" class="text-right">TOTAL:</td>
            <td class="total text-right"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
                <td class="valor text-right">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="info">
            <td colspan="2" class="text-right">TOTAL:</td>
            <td class="total text-right"></td>
        </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

When the document is ready, it's calculated the total for the column with class *valor* and it's shown on both head and foot of the table at the column with class *total*.

The idea is that the user can filter rows typing anything on the input text named **filterbox** and therefore the total should be recalculated.

By this time I'm able to filter rows with the jQuery code bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $rows = $(".table tbody tr");
    var total = 0;

    $rows.each(function () {
        total += parseFloat($(this).find(".valor").text().replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
    });

    $("#filterbox").keyup(function () {
        var filtertext = $(this).val();
        var regex = new RegExp(filtertext, 'i');
        $rows.hide().filter(function () {
            return regex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
    });

    $(".total").html(formataTotal(total.toFixed(2)));
});

function formatTotal(num) {
    var parts = num.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    return parts.join(",");
}
```

I've tried the following to get the total recalculated, but it didn't work:

```
        $("#filterbox").keyup(function () {
        var filtertext = $(this).val();
        var regex = new RegExp(filtertext, 'i');
        $rows.hide().filter(function () {
            return regex.test($(this).text());
        }).each(function () {
            total += parseFloat($(".table tbody tr").find(".valor").text().replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
        }).show();
    });
```

What should I do to get to sum the values recalculated when filtering rows?

Thanks for your attention.
Paulo Ricardo Ferreira

Comment: What is the error you're getting after recalculating?

Comment: Hi, @Arthur Samarcos. There's no error. It simply shows the same total as  all the rows were still showed.

Comment: You are getting the same result because you must inform the script to only sum up visible rows. Try using "total += parseFloat($(".table tbody tr:visible").find(".valor") etc"

Comment: Hi, @Arthur Samarcos. I tried your suggestion, but it made no difference. Still getting the same result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $rows = $(".table tbody tr");
    var total = 0;

$rows.each(function () {
    total += parseFloat($(this).find(".valor").text().replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
});

$("#filterbox").keyup(function () {
    var filtertext = $(this).val();
    var regex = new RegExp(filtertext, 'i');
    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
        return regex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();

    $(".table tbody tr:visible").each(function () {
        total += parseFloat($(this).find(".valor").text().replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
    });
    $(".total").html(formataTotal(total.toFixed(2)));

});

$(".total").html(formataTotal(total.toFixed(2)));
});

function formatTotal(num) {
var parts = num.toString().split(".");
parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
return parts.join(",");
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Arthur Samarcos, it worked! Thanks and sorry for my delay in responding to your answer.